# Why does AND, OR work as expected but an error is shown with XOR?

Tags: logic, scheme, racket, eval

```
(define-syntax e.g.
  (syntax-rules (===>)
    ((e.g. proposition)
     (unless proposition
       (error "invalid proposition: "'proposition)))
    ((e.g. proposition ===> value)
     (let ((result proposition))
       (unless (equal? proposition value)
         (error "invalid proposition: "'proposition
                ", expected "value", got "result))))))

(define my-eval
  (let ((ns (make-base-namespace)))
    (lambda (expr) (eval expr ns))))

(e.g. (my-eval '(and #t #t)) ===> #t)
(e.g. (my-eval '(and #t #f)) ===> #f)
(e.g. (my-eval '(or #t #f)) ===> #t)
(e.g. (my-eval '(or #f #f)) ===> #f)
(e.g. (my-eval '(xor #t #t)) ===> #f)
(e.g. (my-eval '(xor #t #f)) ===> #t)
```

It works correctly for AND,OR but for XOR:

XOR: undefined;
cannot reference an identifier before its definition.

even tough in the REPL seems to work correctly:

> (xor #t #f)
>
> ## t

Comment: also is there any way to see the contents of a namespace? (println namespace) returns #<namespace>

Comment: There's the documentation, which tells you that `xor` is not in `racket/base`.

Comment: also, there is [`namespace-mapped-symbols`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._namespace-mapped-symbols)))

Comment: yes i found the xor here: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html
and yes now i see that there's a section with xor with the intro: "The bindings documented in this section are provided by the racket/bool and racket libraries, but not racket/base."
The question is who has time to read whole documents like that? The way a browse is i go to a page and use ctrl-f to find the function i'm looking for.

Comment: why the division into:  racket/bool and racket libraries, but not racket/base ?
when both they are all Boolean logic?

Comment: tried adding: (require racket/bool) to fix the problem but it doesn't work. Do i need to download it separetly?

Comment: tried adding: (require racket) which has alot of libs right? How can i check if require actually worked?

Comment: 'The question is who has time to read whole documents like that?'  There's this famous acronym...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The question is who has time to read whole documents like that?*

You don't have to read it all in one sitting, but that is where the information is, and Racket has a lot of great documentation.

`eval` can be a bit slippery in Racket; you need to finish setting up the namespace where the `eval` expression is evaluated. One way to do this is to use [`parameterize`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/parameters.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._parameterize%29%29) to create an empty namespace. This needs to happen inside the `lambda` expression, i.e., the environment in which `eval` is evaluated, and you need to be sure that both `racket/base` and `racket/bool` are `require`d:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax e.g.
  (syntax-rules (===>)
    ((e.g. proposition)
     (unless proposition
       (error "invalid proposition: " 'proposition)))
    ((e.g. proposition ===> value)
     (let ((result proposition))
       (unless (equal? proposition value)
         (error "invalid proposition: " 'proposition
                ", expected " value ", got " result))))))

(define my-eval
  (lambda (expr)
    (parameterize ([current-namespace (make-base-empty-namespace)])
      (namespace-require 'racket/base)
      (namespace-require 'racket/bool)
      (eval expr))))

(e.g. (my-eval '(and #t #t)) ===> #t)
(e.g. (my-eval '(and #t #f)) ===> #f)
(e.g. (my-eval '(or #t #f)) ===> #t)
(e.g. (my-eval '(or #f #f)) ===> #f)
(e.g. (my-eval '(xor #t #t)) ===> #f)
(e.g. (my-eval '(xor #t #f)) ===> #t)
```

Comment: so placing (require racket/bool) at the top of the file is not enough?

Comment: is it so complicated on other scheme variants to eval something? what where the reasons for such design? wasn't the scheme philosophy minimalist?

Comment: (e.g. (my-eval '(xor #t #t)) ===> #f)  returns:
xor: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: xor

Comment: and the eval before worked for AND and OR and now it's also broken:
and: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: and

Comment: even after changing (namespace-require 'racket/bool) to 
(namespace-require 'racket)

Comment: @X10D -- I had to add a require and move the `parameterize` expression; the original answer _seemed_ to work for me, but I was testing in an emacs REPL, not running in Dr Racket. When I tested the `e.g.` expressions in the REPL they worked but they failed when run as a program, as you found out. Tested in Dr Racket this time; everything seems to work now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to require `racket/bool`, which provides `xor`, into the namespace used by `my-eval`. One way to do that is to run `(my-eval '(require racket/bool))` before your `xor` tests.

Comment: tried both (require racket/bool) and (require racket) just below #lang racket at the top of the file

Comment: That won't work. For your code above, you need `xor` in the namespace used by `my-eval`, not in the module that defines `e.g.`. Those are two different environments. (If you want to turn the module's environment into a namespace you can use with `eval`, use `define-namespace-anchor` and `namespace-anchor->namespace`.)